# How do we properly print JSON output data in php?

Tags: php, json

I'm using API to pull soccer data from betsapi. As I'm not expert in JSON, I'm sharing my queries here. My json output looks like this:

```
{  
"success":1,
"results":{  
  "season":{  
     "start_time":"1502402400",
     "end_time":"1526335199",
     "has_topgoals":"1",
     "has_leaguetable":"1",
     "has_lineups":"1",
     "name_1":"Premier League 17\/18",
     "name":"Premier League 17\/18"
  },

  "overall":{  
     "tournaments":[  
        {  
           "name":"Premier League",
           "rows":[  
              {  
                 "pos":"1",
                 "sort_pos":"1",
                 "change":"0",
                 "win":"8",
                 "draw":"1",
                 "loss":"0",
                 "goalsfor":"32",
                 "goalsagainst":"4",
                 "points":"25",
                 "pct":null,
                 "team":{  
                    "id":"708",
                    "name":"Man City",
                    "image_id":"17",
                    "cc":"gb"
                 }
              }

              {  
                 "pos":"20",
                 "sort_pos":"20",
                 "change":"0",
                 "win":"1",
                 "draw":"0",
                 "loss":"8",
                 "goalsfor":"2",
                 "goalsagainst":"19",
                 "points":"3",
                 "pct":null,
                 "team":{  
                    "id":"17189",
                    "name":"Crystal Palace",
                    "image_id":"7",
                    "cc":"gb"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
```

And my code to print result is

```
$obj = [''] // code above

$obj = json_decode($data);

foreach($obj as $result){
   echo $result->season->name; // or

   echo $result->overall->tournaments->name; // or
}
```

Though I've tried it with many alternatives, it doesn't print anything neither does it gives any error.

If anyone can point out the errors, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: `var_dump()` json decoded value. `json_decode()` will return null if data can't be decoded.

Comment: @ArtOsi The JSON data output is already there. It's just missing something in looping..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$obj = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($obj); //Should give you your json converted to php array
```

Then, to loop through results

```
foreach ($obj['results'] as $result) {
  echo $result['season']['name'];
}
```

Also to loop through tournaments:

```
foreach ($obj['results']['overall']['tournaments'] as $tournament) {
  echo $tournament['name'];
}
```

To loop through teams in each tournament, try something like this:

```
foreach ($obj['results']['overall']['tournaments'] as $tournament) {
  echo 'Tournament: ' . $tournament['name'] . '<br />';
  foreach ($tournament['rows'] as $row) {
    echo 'Team: #' . $row['team']['id'] . ' ' . $row['team']['name'] . ' (' . $row['team']['image_id'] . ')' . '<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Tournaments loop is working though results are still showing blank.. Any hints to loop through the sub-rows in the tournaments. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: under the tournament 'rows', there is a sub row with "Team'. Can't loop on to get info "image_id". Appreciate for taking time to respond. I'll mark the answer